Не могу собрать новый проект MAUI
При создании нового проекта типа "Приложение .NET MAUI (Майкрософт)", не получается собрать проект. Изменения никакие не вносились.
В файле "MauiProgram.cs" красным подсвечиваются две ошибки:

using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging - Ошибка   CS0234  Тип или имя пространства имен "Extensions" не существует в пространстве имен "Microsoft" (возможно, отсутствует ссылка на сборку).
var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder() - Ошибка    CS0246  Не удалось найти тип или имя пространства имен "MauiApp" (возможно, отсутствует директива using или ссылка на сборку).

Пакет "Разработка с помощью .NET Multi-Platform App UI" свежий - только переустановил (через Visual Studio Installer).
Используемая версия .NET Core - 7.0.117, 8.0.203 (И в том и в том случае ошибки повторяются).
Полное содержимое файла MauiProgram.cs:
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace MauiApp2
{
    public static class MauiProgram
    {
        public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
        {
            var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            builder
                .UseMauiApp<App>()
                .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
                {
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
                });

#if DEBUG
            builder.Logging.AddDebug();
#endif

            return builder.Build();
        }
    }
}



Похоже на то, что у вас не установились пакеты. Почему? Не знаю... К примеру Microsoft.Extensions.Logging - это NuGet пакет, официальный. Попробуйте открыть NuGet и посмотреть, стоит-ли у вас там все, восстановлены эти пакеты или нет, ну и так далее.

@EvgeniyZ, у меня установлены следующие NuGet пакеты: Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug (8.0.0), Microsoft.Maui.Controls (8.0.7), Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility (8.0.7). Причем, Maui пакеты подсвечены во вкладке обновления (8.0.14), но при попытке установить более новые версии - подтверждаю установку, принимая лицензии, ожидаю и... получаю сообщение  "Сбой при восстановлении пакета. Откат изменений пакета для «MauiApp1»".

Такая же картинка при установке любого другого NuGet пакета. Хотя в других типах проектов установка работает корректно. Например, пакет Newtonsoft.Json установился без каких-либо проблем в проекте без использования MAUI.

Окно вывода смотрите, там пишет все ошибки, включая подробные ошибки установки пакетов.
